# Problem with casting activeX object onto my object

Tags: winforms, com, wpf-controls, activex

I'm trying to use Windows From as ActiveX control inside SAP B1. Inside that control I host WPF control. It works great except when I try to cast activeX object onto my class so I can use all the methods on my class. But when I try to do that I get an exception. What is wrong?

I did registration and all that stuff. I can even display that control inside SAP with some handcrafted data (initialized in control constructor). Although I'm not sure if this is more general problem and not SAP-specific.

Welcome any suggestions and thanks in advance.

The message I got is:
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'CapacityCalendarControl.CapacityCalendar'

```
[Guid("9A2F1CCB-8DC0-4CE5-B3C7-403A1A8CDCE2")]
[ProgId("kamil.calendar.control")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public partial class CapacityCalendar : UserControl
{
  //internals...
}
```

Comment: You didn't post the code that bombed.

Answer (score 1):

A System.__ComObject (a COM wrapper) cannot be cast to a .NET class. The simplest way for you is to use TLBImport (Type Library Import Tool), I think, if your activeX is equipped with a .TLB (external or embedded).

See here for more: [Tool for creating .NET wrappers for a COM DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120690/tool-for-creating-net-wrappers-for-a-com-dll)

Comment: But I made my activeX from net assembly and I cannot convert it back to net assembly, at least that is what I get from Tlbimp.

Comment: TlbImp will create .NET classes to use a non .NET COM object (=Active X). I don't understand the "I made my ActivX from net assembly" statement?