# Changing the behavior of a COM object

Tags: c#, .net, com, hook, code-generation

I have a somewhat complex library (something.dll) that I can use via COM. This library is unmanaged. Among other things, this library connects to a system and allows me to communicate with it.

I have a lot of .NET (managed) applications that use this library. Because the way the library communicates with the system is deprecated, I would like to change the behavior of this library without touching the .NET applications.

One of my approaches is to hook COM calls, but I've had a lot of fights with this (e.g. I can intercept some calls but when returning from the hook function it seems that only nulls are received), so I was wondering if I could just "mock" the library.

In other words, is there some tool that I can use that will analyze the library (like as VS Object Browser) and generate all the stubs needed so that I can just change the way it communicates and fill by myself all properties and implement all the methods by myself? Or any other idea to solve the problem?

Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2120690/tool-for-creating-net-wrappers-for-a-com-dll

Comment: @AndreyBelykh I don't want to generate the wrappers (VS does a pretty good job with this), what I would like to have is a tool that analyses the COM library and creates a skeleton of all functions and properties automatically, so that I can just provide an implementation to a new COM library that provides the same functionality but with a different black box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a new project that contains a class which instantiates your COM object. Expose it to COM with the same GUID. Then you'd just change and expose the methods as necessary and deploy the new DLL.

Not sure where you'd stand with the existing DLL after that - can it's GUID be regenerated?

Comment: Not sure on what you mean by the GUID being regenerated, but the overall idea is good. Please note - I don't need the old COM object - the point is to expose the same things as the previous one, but with a different implementation (I mostly want to change how the data is retrieved), thus allowing existing applications to transparently use the new COM object. There is a con to this approach though, the library contains a lot of functions and properties and what I would like to use, provided that I take this approach, is something that would generate the stubs for me (less error prone and work).

Comment: I guess you could as a once off use reflection to generate an interface of the stubs to avoid writing them by hand. Then auto implement that interface. There might even be a tool that will do this for you